# Need php script just like used by mysmartprice dot com on Go To Store button (URL Cloaking)

Tags: php, url, cloaking

Need code of php script used for example by mysmartprice dot com on their "Go To Store" button for URL cloaking.

Comment: ehm, what? If you want people to help you, please provide a more detailed explanation (which button?) of your problem and what you have tried so far.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried)? This seems like a `give me teh codez` type question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I got your question right, but this is my guess of you mean:

Use PHP's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) method like this:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET["p"]))
        exit("No parameter \"p\"");

    $p = $_GET["p"];
    header("LOCATION: $p");
?>
```

Save the file as redir.php and then use it as http://mysite.com/redir.php?p=http://google.com/.

Comment: Thank you so much Ineentho you are bang on....Thanks once again...